# Comunication between webview and main window without remote module

Tags: webview, electron

Is there a way to communicate between the webview and the main window without enabling the remote module ?

```html
<webview src="http://www.google.com/" enableremotemodule="false"></webview>
```

> When this attribute is false the guest page in webview will not have access to the remote module. The remote module is avaiable by default.
>
> https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#enableremotemodule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite what you asked but I took heed of the Electron team's [warning](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/webview-tag#enableremotemodule) and opted to use `iframes` rather than `webviews`

> We currently recommend to not use the webview tag and to consider
>   alternatives, like iframe, Electron's BrowserView, or an architecture
>   that avoids embedded content altogether.

I've had success using [Window.postMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) but I am far from an "expert" on any of this.

> The window.postMessage() method safely enables cross-origin
>   communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a
>   pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded
>   within it.

Comment: this is exactly what  I need, I wasn't aware of that warning, I guess I should use an `iframe` instead, thanks!

Comment: As far as I know the `webview` it's wrapping an iframe, will this work inside the webview as well ?